# Return all rows of AspNetUserClaims - get every claim in application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

ASP .NET Identity using OWIN auth -
I would like to do the following:
A user should be able to create their prefered username. Email, though a claim, should be unique - Consider the following scenario.

User registers locally at first. User decides to use FB or Google to login on their second visit. Through scoping OAUTH I retrieve their FB/Google registered emails.
At this point, I would like to:
1. See if a claim exists with that particular email.
2. Retrieve the user ID associated with that email.
3. Insert a new row in the AspNetUserLogins table, for that particular user and his/her particular provider.

This way, unless the user has used different emails on site/fb/google, they will be able to use all 3 to log on the same user profile.

But to do this, I need to somehow retrieve all claims. I've tried this through ApplicationDbContext, and IdentityDbContext, but I haven't found a mapping for claims. Only users, and claims seem tied to a user.

Is there a way to retrieve all the claims in the DB? (Or perhaps someone can suggest me doing this in a different, more convenient way.)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

The way I've worked around this is add a new model item in my project that maps to the claims table and query that.
Maybe not the cleanest of solutions but it seems to work alright !

Comment: Why not just use the email address as the UserName?  This is what I do, and I then check the email address against existing users when someone logs in with Facebook (e.g.) and if the Facebook email matches, they are linked together.  I don't see the need for an additional view at all.

Comment: I would like my users to be able to choose their login name as they see fit :(

Comment: AspNet.Identity v2 includes an email column in the user table.  You could use that...

Comment: I haven't seen one, I've only seen one in the claims table. But I've appended ApplicationUser with an Email property and that's what I've resulted doing in the end. :) Thanks for the comment though.